# Instagram Basic Display API - Submit App for Review

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have implemented the Instagram Basic Display API for my web project, but while submitting the app for review on facebook developer site, it's asking only for the iOS & android app under the "App Verification" section for testing.

How can I add the website URL there, instead of the apps. Below are the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Please help me out to resolve this issue, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: If you have an Android and an iOS version of your app configured in the dashboard, then those need to be included in your submission.

Comment: @CBroe Let say if I have not implemented the same functionality in my app yet,  so is there any way to mark them as optional while submitting the app for review? Also my major concern is "WHY WEBSITE OPTION IS NOT COMING THERE" ?? Can you please guide me for this part as well? Thanks buddy!

Comment: Why should that appear in the first place, in these locations? The second screenshot is asking you to add missing stuff - if you _have_ your website platform properly set up already, then there likely simply isn't anything to do in _this_ step.